# How to automatic break lines in latex?

Tags: latex

I have searched but nothing useless, only "use \newline" or "use \".

I'm creating a simple latex document to store any texts instead of using .txt, and the problem is that the pdf document contains the lines going towards right until they go out of the paper.

I'm using this simple code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=5mm,
    top=20mm,
}

\begin{document}
    
\section{Text 1}
Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlabore etdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat.Duisauteiruredolorinreprehenderitinvoluptatevelitessecillum doloreeufugiatnullapariatur.Excepteursintoccaecatcupidatatnonproident,suntinculpaquiofficiadeseruntmollitanimidestlaborum.

\end{document}
```

Since latex sees it as a one word, it refuses to break it since it doenst know its hyphenation. But I would like to allow latex to break it regardless. Any thoughts ?

Remarks: I already have used:
`\hspace{0pt}`
`\leavevmode\nobreak\hspace{0pt}`
`\mbox{Loremip...larorum.}`

Nothing worked.

Comment: You could help latex find hyphenation points: `Lorem\-ipsumdo\-lorsit\-amet,conse\-cteturad\-ipiscinge\-lit,seddo\-eiusmod\-temporin\-cididuntut\-labore etdolorem\-agna\-aliqua.Uten\-imadminim\-veniam,quis\-nostrudex\-ercitati\-onullamcol\-aborisnisiu\-taliquipex\-eacommodo\-consequat\-.Duisau\-t\-eiruredo\-lorinrepreh\-enderiti\-nvoluptate\-velitesse\-cillu\-m doloreeu\-fugiat\-nullap\-ariatur.Exce\-pteursint\-occaecatc\-upidatat\-nonproide\-nt,suntin\-culpaqui\-officiades\-eruntmollitanimidestlaborum.`

Comment: So, there basically is no way to do something as simple as stopping LaTeX from overflowing text except breaking it manually. Wow.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got why *nothing worked*. See my code below, that I managed to compile successfully after editing your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

You basically have two ways to *force* hyphenation here.

1. As in the comment by SamCarter, you manually split words within text, just using `\-` where necessary. I did it below in line 18 (6 from bottom).
2. You add to your preamble the command `\hyphenation{word-to-split}`: I did this below to hyphenate the word in line 20 (4 from bottom). Notice that, in this case, you use `-` instead of `\-` within the braces `{}` enclosing the argument.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=5mm,
    top=20mm,
}

\hyphenation{Duisauteiruredolorinre-prehenderitinvoluptatevelitesse-cillum doloreeufugiatnullapariatur}

\begin{document}
    
\section{Text 1}

Loremipsumdolorsitamet, consecteturadipiscingelit, 
seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagna. 
Uten\-imadminimveniam, 
quisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat. 
Duisauteiruredolorinreprehenderitinvoluptatevelitessecillumdoloreeufugiatnullapariatur. 
Excepteursintoccaecatcupidatatnonproident, 
suntinculpaquiofficiadeseruntmollitanimidestlaborum. 
\end{document}
```

Finally, if the full stop character `.` is not followed by a space, two separate words may be interpreted as one and the command `\hyphenation` may not work as expected. Not sure that this was the detail making you write that *nothing worked*, but be careful to this too.